# How to save/serializing a glm model as zip/pickle file?

Tags: machine-learning, zip, pickle, statsmodels

I built a tweedie glm model using statsmodels.
Just wondering how to save/serializing it as zip file or pkl file?

I tried

```py
from statsmodels.formula.api import glm

formula4 = "y ~ x1 + C(x2)"

mod4 = glm(formula=formula4, var_weights = 'one', data=train, family=sm.families.Tweedie())
res4 = mod4.fit()

import pickle

filename = 'test.pkl'
#Use pickle to save your object to a file:
pickle.dump(mod4, open(filename, 'wb'))
```

But the saved pickle file is too large.
Any idea?

--
Answer:
not to use formula directly in the model building process. use dmatrices to process the data ahead. then save the model, the result is around 10kb.

Comment: `remove_data` removes all nobs arrays. call `summary()` before remove_data to keep inferential statistics. https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/1729 https://github.com/statsmodels/statsmodels/issues/3563

Comment: note, when using formulas, then we still need to pickle the original data. Patsy's formula information cannot be pickled and it needs to be rebuild using the original dataframe.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Tried the 'remove_data = True'. Able to shrink the size, but it's still too large..